# What is wrong with my object spread operator usage?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, operator-keyword, ecmascript-2016, spread-syntax

```
var color3 = {
    name: 'Black',
    type: 'special',
    rating: 1
};

var rateColor3 = (colorName, Nrating) => ({ ...colorName, Nrating });
console.log(color3.rating); ///// 1
console.log(rateColor3(color3, 6).rating);//////1
console.log(color3.rating);//////1
```

I want to use object spread operator while keeping color3 immutable,
But the output of my 2nd console.log is 1 instead of 6, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the whole object. `Nrating ` is a completely different property than `rating`

Comment: um Nrating != rating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a the value `6` to the key `NRating` to the object, not the existing `rating`.

So your object would look like this:

```
{
    name: 'Black',
    type: 'special',
    rating: 1,
    Nrating: 6
}
```

To override the existing `rating` property, you have to do:

```
var rateColor3 = (colorName, Nrating) => ({ ...colorName, rating: Nrating });
```

or change your parameter `Nrating` to `rating`.

```js
var color3 = {
    name: 'Black',
    type: 'special',
    rating: 1
};

var rateColor3 = (colorName, rating) => ({ ...colorName, rating });

console.log(rateColor3(color3, 6));
```

Comment: _"You are applying a new property to your object called Nrating"_ - actually, that is not true. And still it doesn't answer the OP question.

Comment: @kinduser try `console.log(rateColor3(color3, 6).Nrating)` using the original code.

Comment: It's not _applying_ a new property. It's just a basic dot notation to _get_ specified key value.

Comment: Oh sorry for beeing semantically incorrect. I'll fix it shortly!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not mutating the original `color3` object, but returning a new one. Secondly:

`({ ...colorName, Nrating });`

will return a new object with a fourth prop `Nrating: 6`, since it's a shorthand for object assignment. You'll have to simply assign the value to the `rating` key instead.

```js
var color3 = {
    name: 'Black',
    type: 'special',
    rating: 1
};

var rateColor3 = (colorName, Nrating) => ({ ...colorName, rating: Nrating });

console.log(rateColor3(color3, 6));
```

Comment: The fourth property is `Nrating: 6`. The variable isn't evaluated when using it as the property name, only as the value.

Comment: @Barmar Dunno how I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nrating needs a property name

```
var color3 = {
   name: 'Black',
   type: 'special',
   rating: 1
};

var rateColor3 = (colorName, Nrating) => ({ ...colorName, rating: Nrating });
console.log(color3.rating); ///// 1
console.log(rateColor3(color3, 6).rating);//////6
console.log(color3.rating);//////1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a new property `Nrating`. Change your `rating` to `Nrating`.

```js
var color3 = {
    name: 'Black',
    type: 'special',
    rating: 1
};

var rateColor3 = (colorName, Nrating) => ({ ...colorName, Nrating });
console.log(color3.rating); ///// 1
console.log(rateColor3(color3, 6).Nrating);//////6
console.log(color3.rating);//////1
```